# Error 40 in SQL Server and no service instance

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL server 2014 newly. When I am opening SQL Server Management Studio and giving localhost as server name then I am getting error 40 i.e.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

While installing the SQL Server there were no instances given by me so there is only default instance. I read many other posts here in Stack overflow and also found that there is no service like MSSQLSERVICE in my services that I can run..

I am not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: are you on Windows 10?

Comment: Can you see under Services "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"?  if so start that

Comment: Yeah I am on win 10.. There is only SQL Server VSS Writer service there and nothing else related to SQL..

Comment: Are you running Windows 10 memory compressor.  If so, I recall there was a known issue.

Comment: I do not have idea about that.. Can you please guide me how to tell if I have memory compressor? And if this is the issue how to get this resolved??

Comment: ***WHAT exactly*** did you install? **Only** the Management Studio? Then that is **just** the GUI tool - **NOT** the database engine! Of course you don't have any database instance - you haven't installed one....